# Точный поиск по запросу

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
У меня имеется запрос который возвращает информации про автобилей(гос номера, цвет, обьем).
Теперь мне надо когда пользователь выводит в Textbox гос номер машины, тогда должен показать результаты.
Как можно сделать процедуру с параметрами. Я попробовал так:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare
    @number nvarchar(100);
Select t1.name, t2.number
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t2.number = @number
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Возможно, вам пригодится эта инструкция: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169/181472)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметры следует перечислять после объявления имени хранимой процедуры до ключевого слова `AS`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
    @a  int,
    @b  datetime,
    @c  varchar(50),
    @d  decimal(7,2)
AS
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

Параметры обязательно должны быть в "заголовке" процедуры. То есть они должны быть **объявлены**. Вы в коде выше всего лишь объявили локальную переменную `@number`.

Следуя приведенной выше логике, процедура с одним параметром типа `nvarchar(100)` должна выглядеть вот так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
    @number  nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  -- в теле процедуры используйте параметр как обычную переменную
END
```